# XeLaTeX "Broken pipe" error

Tags: xetex, errors

Edit: I cleaned up this first post to make it all a bit more clear.

I am trying to compile my tex files using `XeLaTeX`.
This is the minimal code I wrote to try:

---

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Standard packages
\usepackage[right=2.8cm,left=2.8cm,top=3.2cm,bottom=3.0cm, headheight=16pt]{geometry}

% Other packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The compile command I use: `xelatex file.tex`

The error:

```
... (normal behaviour)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex)) (./file.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
[1] (./file.aux) )xelatex.exe: fwrite: Broken pipe
```

Whenever I compile using `xelatex --no-pdf file.tex` and after that `xdvipdfmx file.xdv` it seems to work fine. Another way is by executing `latexmk --xelatex file.tex`. I am trying to understand why I get a `Broken pipe` error.

Comment: please add code inline not as external links (the question is archived for ever but those links will break)  The log shows no error, it is just incomplete so hard to debug with no code available, can you make a small test file that shows this behaviour and add it to your question? Also what happens if you directly run xeetx on the commandline with this file rather than via the editor?

Comment: The logs are pretty big but if you want to have it all embedded, I'll do that. When I compile my code using `xelatex Resume.pdf` I get the same error.
Edit, I can't add the log as you requested, too many characters (I don't even understand why you'd like a thread being bloated with a big log)

Comment: If you posted an example we could generate a log... it doesn't need to be your real cv, you can make it shorter and fake the words as long as it shows the same error (not terminating?) if you run it on the comandline do you get a tex error? the log you linked to shows no error it just stops unfinished?

Comment: Okay, so I shortened my template to this (sorry, the stackexchange editor is just beyond terrible, I can't paste code in a normal way here): https://del.dog/uqedojevuh

The log: https://del.dog/oginuxuvax

Comment: as you see code in comments doesn't really work, best to add it to teh question in a code block (the `{}` button)  also I won't be able to run that without `layout.tex`

Comment: I embedded `layout.tex` in the code, `Sublime Text 3` seems to compile just fine with `XeLaTeX`

Comment: Thanks I added it to your question, but I also tried it locally and get no error? (using texlive 2019 xetex)

Comment: I am using `tlmgr revision 49885 (2019-01-31 20:27:00 +0100), TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2018`. From what I know, `XeTeX` is something else than `XeLaTeX`. It all seems rather difficult to understand. So initially, compiling with `XeLaTeX` requires you to compile using this command: `xelatex file.tex`. However, I am getting the broken pipe error. If I compile using `latexmk` it works: `latexmk --xelatex file.tex`


What command do you use to compile the code?

Maybe it's good to note that I use a Windows 10 machine and not a Linux distro.

Comment: you are clearly using xelatex rather than xetex as the document is using latex rather than plan tex commands such as `\documentclass` and you have an editor comment `% !TEX program = xelatex` to tell your editor to use xelatex. I simply typed `xelatex file` on the commandline. The only way I can see that you could get a broken pipe with such a command is ifyts internal call to xdvipdfmx failed which should never happen, try `xelatex --no-pdf file` see if that runs to completion, making a xdv file, then try `xdvipdfmx file.xdv` to generate the pdf.

Comment: Yes, running the `--no-pdf` command and then using `xdvipdfmx` seems to work. Is there any way to fix the internal call?

Comment: I can't see how it can fail:-) Something very odd going on.

Answer (score 0):

For `Visual Code` with `LaTeX-Workshop`, my workaround is to use `latexmk` as mentioned above. This however is a workaround and not a fix.

I edited my visual studio recipe `"latex-workshop.latex.tools"` to:

```
    "name": "xelatex",
    "command": "latexmk",
    "args": [
        "--xelatex",
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%"
    ]
```